# Room availability between two dates (beginner)

Tags: c#, sql, service

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013 and working on a project for my class in which I am making a very very simple hotel booking system to be used for staff to create new customers and book them into a room.

When the user tries to book the same room twice or it overlaps I need the system to not allow it and I'm trying to take care of the in the service. (see below)

```
public override void Add(Booking booking)
{
    // Don't allow a new booking if the room is already out.

    var currentBooking = _ctx.Bookings
        .Where(b => b.RoomId == booking.RoomId)
        .Select(b => (b.CheckOut < booking.CheckIn 
                       && b.CheckIn  < booking.CheckIn) 
                      || (b.CheckIn > booking.CheckOut 
                       && b.CheckOut > booking.CheckOut ))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (currentBooking != null)
    {
        throw new BookingException("The Room is already out on that date.");
    }

    booking.CheckIn = DateTime.Now.Date;  
    _ctx.Set<Booking>().Add(booking);
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that no matter what date I put in when creating a new booking the system throws the BookingException "room is already out", even though my DBseed only has two dates in it. (see below)

```
context.Bookings.AddOrUpdate(
            b => b.CheckIn,
            new Booking()
            {
                CheckIn = new DateTime(2015, 09, 12),                    
                CheckOut = new DateTime(2015, 09, 21),
                RoomId = 1,
                CustomerId = 1,
            },
            new Booking()
            {
                CheckIn = new DateTime(2015, 06, 01),
                CheckOut = new DateTime(2015, 06,08),
                RoomId = 2,
                CustomerId = 2
            });
```

I'm thinking my problem is in the service, but I am having trouble figuring  out what the specific problem is.

Comment: What specific values are being used for `Booking booking` in your `Add()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currentBooking is bool hence it always throwing the exception, ie it's never null.

Switching the if statement to check for true seemed to highlight an issue with the filtering in the Linq. I have to say I just rewrote the select to this, I've only run a couple of tests but this seems to work:

```
        currentBooking = _ctx.Booking
            .Where(b => b.RoomId == booking.RoomId)
            .Select(b => (booking.CheckIn < b.CheckOut && booking.CheckIn > b.CheckIn))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentBooking)
        {
            throw new Exception("The Room is already out on that date.");
        }
```

Comment: Works like a charm now!  Thanks a million :)